# WampSharp unable to connect to Poloniex?

Tags: c#, wamp, wampsharp

Here is my very simple code using the latest prerelease version of WampSharp:

```
        var channelFactory = new DefaultWampChannelFactory();
        var channel = channelFactory.CreateMsgpackChannel("wss://api.poloniex.com", "realm1");
        await channel.Open();

        var realmProxy = channel.RealmProxy;

        Console.WriteLine("Connection established");

        int received = 0;
        IDisposable subscription = null;

        subscription =
            realmProxy.Services.GetSubject("ticker")
                      .Subscribe(x =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Got Event: " + x);

                received++;

                if (received > 5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Closing ..");
                    subscription.Dispose();
                }
            });

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Doesn't work though, the code within the subscription never runs.  Tried it with `CreateJsonChannel` as well, that doesn't work either.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: I'm trying to use the poloniex websocket api. Have you got working sample code?

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: It's their API, not your code. Their API is not sending data. I tried it with the posted node.js example and no data comes back either.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine. Just get rid of the Console.ReadLine - it blocks the WebSocket thread and therefore WampSharp can't get any further messages.
You can add a Console.ReadLine to your Main instead.

See also [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: That wouldn't make sense as their example shows exactly this: http://wampsharp.net/wamp2/roles/subscriber/getting-started-with-subscriber/

Comment: The difference is that in the example you linked to, they use ```channel.Open.Wait(5000)``` and not ```await channel.Open()```. The await keyword causes the next lines to run on the WebSocket's thread.